# GridView OnRowDeleting event not being called under IIS6, works fine in dev env

Tags: asp.net, .net, gridview, iis-6

I have a weird situation and would be grateful for any help or insight.

I am developing on Windows 8, Visual Studio 2012. I have an ASP.NET app, targeting .NET framework 2.0.

This includes a GridView with this definition

```
  <asp:Label ID="Message" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Text="" />
  <asp:GridView ID="grdDocs" runat="server"
        BackColor="LightGoldenrodYellow" BorderColor="Tan" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="2" 
        EnableModelValidation="False" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="None" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="false" AutoGenerateEditButton="false"
        OnRowDeleting="GridViewDeleteEventHandler" EnableTheming="False" EnableViewState="False">
      <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="PaleGoldenrod" />
      <FooterStyle BackColor="Tan" />
      <HeaderStyle BackColor="Tan" Font-Bold="True" />
      <PagerStyle BackColor="PaleGoldenrod" ForeColor="DarkSlateBlue" 
          HorizontalAlign="Center" />
      <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="DarkSlateBlue" ForeColor="GhostWhite" />
    <Columns>
      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" DataField="DocumentID" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" SortExpression="DocumentID" />
      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date" DataField="DisplayDate" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" SortExpression="DisplayDate" />
      <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Document" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
        DataNavigateUrlFields="FileName"
        DataNavigateUrlFormatString="prv/{0}" Target="_blank"
        DataTextField="DisplayName" SortExpression="DisplayName" />
    </Columns>
  </asp:GridView>
```

In the code is an event handler

```
    protected void GridViewDeleteEventHandler(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        var id = grdDocs.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text;

        Message.Text = "Deleting document with ID " + id;

        OleDbConnection db = new clsUtilities().OpenDB();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("delete from PrivateDocuments where DocumentID = " + id, db);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        db.Close();

        grdDocs.Rows[e.RowIndex].Visible = false;
    }
```

Now, on my test machine this works. The grid shows "Delete" at the beginning of each row (not very aesthetic, but at least it's there). When I click on it, my event fires and the row is removed.

HOWEVER, when copied onto the production server - Windows Server 2003, IIS 6, "xcopy deployment", the Delete button clicks don't seem to do anything at all.

Turning on the web browser status bar shows a postback when hovering over the link, but clicking absolutely does nothing; I don't even think it is calling the event.

Any thoughts?

**EDIT**: Now working.

I appreciate those who attempted to assist, though it was not the case that the event was not working, more that it simply did not appear to even be firing. That made me believe it was an IIS / .NET issue rather than a coding issue.

Anyhow, I decided to change the .NET framework I was targetting so I ramped it from 2.0 to 4.0, recompiled and redeployed, changing the relevant IIS settings. This worked. Out of interest, I changed it to target .NET framework 2.0 again, redeployed, and reconfigured IIS as appropriate and again it worked. So, I am confused, but all I can pin it down to is a glitch with the IIS config at the time. Weirdly, I did not make any changes to IIS when installing in the first place.

So, lesson is - if you find this post because of a similar problem, try your IIS app settings and target framework ...

Comment: What actually does the delete? Can you post the code for the delete logic?

Comment: In case you have handled the exceptions which usually happens when deleting a row i.e  Child rows exist with the Foreign key contraints, check the logs if this is the reason why Delete fails every time. Also please show the  relevant code.

Comment: Code added - not great code :/ but added anyhow !

Comment: To clarify, I am not saying the delete is failing but rather the event doesn't even seem to fire.